# Block in a loop for paging

Tags: objective-c, block, instagram

With the following code I'm trying to read the Instagram API content with paging. In the FOR loop I intent to call the method loopData to get the content with a block which has in every loop a new page id.

...

```
    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++)
    {
       NSLog(@"Loop count: %i", a);

       [self loopData];
    }

-(void)loopData 
{
    NSString *next;
    next = [Globals sharedGlobalData].nextMaxId;

    [client getUserMedia:[userTextField stringValue]
                   count:kCount
                   minId:-1
                   maxId:next
                 success:^(NSArray *media) {
                     [textView setString:[media description]];

                     NSLog(@"Next_Max_Id: %@ ", [Globals sharedGlobalData].nextMaxId);

                 }
                 failure:^(NSError *error, NSInteger statusCode) {
                     [self logError:@"media" error:error statusCode:statusCode];
                 }
     ];
}
```

My problem is, that the block runs thee times, but not in every loop cycle. The block runs after the for loop is finished. Therefore the new page id can't passed to the block.

The Log looks like this:
Loop 1
Loop 2
Loop 3

Read content through block
Read content through block
Read content through block

Many thanks for ideas!!

--- Implementation of getUserMedia

```
// Get a user's media
- (void)getUserMedia:(NSString*)userId // Can be 'self' for the current user
               count:(int)count 
               minId:(int)minId // -1 for start
               maxId:(int)maxId // -1 for no upper limit
             success:(void (^)(NSArray* media))success
             failure:(void (^)(NSError* error, NSInteger statusCode))failure {
    // Setup the parameters
    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInt:count], @"count",  nil];
    if (minId > 0) [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:minId] forKey:@"minId"];
    if (maxId > 0) [parameters setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:maxId] forKey:@"maxId"];

    // Fire the get request
    [self getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"users/%@/media/recent", userId]
       modelClass:[InstagramMedia class]
       parameters:parameters
       collection:success
           single:nil
          failure:failure];
}
```

Comment: I'd expect anything taking success or failure blocks to execute them asynchronously. What's the implementation of `getUserMedia:count:minId:maxId:success:failure:` look like?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I'm trying to use the Instagram wrapper [link] (github.com/stuartkhall/instagram) and I posted the implementation of getUserMedia above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The blocks you pass into this method are executed asynchronously. The client starts an asynchronous network request and immediately returns when you call this method. Once the network request succeeds or fails, one of the blocks you passed to it is invoked. This is pretty much the standard behavior of any API that takes blocks to use for callbacks like this.

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do inside the blocks with respect to the `nextID` and whatnot, but you need to know this: 1) The blocks will not run within the loop and 2) they will not run in any guaranteed order. So whatever problem you are trying to solve, you will need to keep that in mind.

Hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @CarlVeazey! What I'm trying to do is, reading web content with pagination. The Instagram API returns only a set of data (e.g. user media) and for the next set you need to call the API with a new url (nextid). I'm really new to Objective-C and I don't now, how to handle this case. Do you know a proper way to load a web content with pagination. Meaning loop with a new nextid as long as this value is not null? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you trying to do some sort of endless scrolling thing where you load additional pages as the user scrolls near the end of the list or something? Also does `[Globals sharedGlobalData].nextMaxId` increment the value automatically or something? Although, it seems like the data will load with all up to the maxID since you're passing -1... if you're doing pagination of the data you'll probably want to keep track of the lower limit as well to not fetch information you don't need. But I think your UI requirements might dictate your approach here.

Comment: Thanks @CarlVeazey! The idea is to load the data completely through all pages and extract (JSON) all relevant data into a array for further handlings. The global variable `[Globals sharedGlobalData].nextMaxId` stores the extracted value of the nextid from each page and pass it to the next url request. With this value (nextid) I'm able to load the next set of data. At this time I'm testing some ways to loop through web sites with passing a new url in every loop. Do you know an other way to do this?

Comment: Sorry to take awhile in responding. Since each request is dependent on getting the next ID, you should use an `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` subclasses that call this client method. Then define dependencies between the operations such that one won't execute until all its predecessors have (and should in theory have the correct next ID. Also - in your code maybe you have a typo. Should the values called into the client method for nextID and MaxID be switched? I'd think we want minimum of the next ID and no limit to the max.

Comment: There are other ways to do it, of course - using the completion block to chain callback after callback works quite well also. Finally, I don't know what information about a user the API tells you, but if you can know the count of their media beforehand, possibly you could just make a single request passing -1 for both next and max ID. Something to look into if that's possible I think that would be comparatively simple.

Comment: @techcharger hey, did this answer help you? Or do you still need help?